# How to make a 2d shooter game interesting?

Tags: game-design, multiplayer, online

Im asking what can i implement in a online multiplayer 2d shooter to make it more interesting the idea i have(i know how to make it) doesn't seem so fun what can i add to a lastman standing 2d shooter game that is not to hard to make in java?
I know how to make multiplayer games online.

Comment: Such open-ended questions with no "right" or "wrong" answers are not a good fit for a question&answer site. When you want to brainstorm ideas, you might want to try a discussion forum.

Comment: Ok next time i ask a similar question i will pur ir in a discussion forum.

Comment: this is not opinion based. i vote for re-opening. there are serious studies around self determination theory that quantify properly what make games interesting. Actually the sub-text proposed by stackexchange here is opposite of the truth. This is a bad question that can give birth to nice answers.

Comment: @v.oddou When you look at the question under this aspect, you will notice that it is far too vague. "What makes a game interesting" is a topic people have written whole books about. So when you don't want this question closed as "primarily opinion-based" it would need to be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Most games are interesting if you can play them with friends.
2. Start simple, go complex. You can make the simplest possible game, and test if your friends like it. I bet they will give you more suggestions.
3. KISS principle: keep is simple, stupid (check TeeWorlds for an example). It is much harder to make simple (to play) games, rather than complex and unintuitive games.
4. Make it easy to mod/extend your game (not MC-style). Make it possible for your friends add new features/levels/enemies/etc. to the game using a ***simple*** editor.
5. Make it an MMO (more players->more fun). The only downside is that it need to be *over*-performant, so it can handle >400 players.
6. Add more game-modes, so everyone can play it as xe likes. Maybe most of them can come as mods/plugins.
7. Make it a web/HTML5 game. Some people are particularly against downloading any kind of executable content, be it .JAR, .EXE, or whatever. Plus, if you make it a web game, it might be easier to get people check it out. (Counter-example, Minecraft is played by millions, but it is not on the web...)